# how to convert a panda column into big query table date format

Tags: python, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a panda dataframe with a column with date format as below:

PublishDate= 2018-08-31
I used panda to_gbq() function to dump data into a bigquery table. Before dumping data, I make sure that the format of columns match with table scheme. publishedate is date only in bigquery table. How can achieve something similar to:

```
     df['PublishDate'] = df['PublishDate'].astype('?????')
```

I tried datetime64[D] and

```
     df['PublishDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PublishDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce').dt.date
     df['PublishDate'] = [time.to_date() for time in df['PublishDate']]
```

but those didn't work!

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue

Found that according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html) you can provide

table_schema : list of dicts, optional

So in my case adding

```
table_schema = [{'name':'execution_date','type': 'DATE'}]
```

worked

Full Line:

```
 pdg.to_gbq(table_for_uploading, upload_table, project_id=project_id, if_exists='replace', credentials=gbq_credentials,table_schema = [{'name':'execution_date','type': 'DATE'}])
```

Comment: You are a hero. This works with Datetime's as well, where everything else was failing.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, pandas-gbq [doesn't seem to have support for the DATE type](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#supported-data-types). So your best option is probably exporting your column as a TIMESTAMP and then converting it to a DATE with an SQL query.

```
df['PublishTimestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['PublishDate'],
    format='%Y-%m-%d',
    errors='coerce'
)
df.to_gbq("YOUR-DATASET.YOUR-TABLE", project_id="YOUR-PROJECT")

client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
table_ref = client.dataset("YOUR-DATASET").table("YOUR-TABLE")
job_config.destination = ref_table
job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"

sql = """
    SELECT
      *,
      DATE(PublishTimestamp) as PublishDate
    FROM
      `YOUR-PROJECT.YOUR-DATASET.YOUR-TABLE`
"""

query_job = client.query(
    sql,
    job_config=job_config
)
query_job.result()
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find support for Date type in pandas-gbq.

Another option is to insert with the bigquery client:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


def chunks(l, chunk_size):
    for i in range(0, len(l), chunk_size):
        yield l[i:i + chunk_size]


CLIENT_ROW_LIMIT = 10000
SCHEMA = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('...'),
]

def push_with_date(df):
    client = bigquery.Client(project='...')
    dataset = client.dataset('...')
    table_ref = dataset.table('...')
    rows = [row.tolist() for index, row in df.iterrows()]
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks(rows, CLIENT_ROW_LIMIT)):
        print('pushing', i)
        errors = client.insert_rows(table_ref, chunk, SCHEMA)
        if errors:
            # Handle
            raise Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one. this works just as a workaround.
without to_gbq.

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=table_schema, source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
)
load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
)
```